# Magento 2: Exclude Google ReCaptcha for specific forms

Tags: magento2, forms, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

We are using Google ReCaptcha for signup forms. We have created some more custom forms for which we would like to exclude the validation. Currently the re-catpcha is not showing in the form but on submit it gives error message "Invalid ReCaptcha validation"

The form is added as a CMS page where it includes the {{block}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I override the ReCaptcha observer using Virtual type class

In di.xml added the following:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\CreateUserObserver"
                 type="Vendor\Module\Observer\ReCaptchaObserver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="isCheckRequired"
                      xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\IsCheckRequired\Frontend\CreateUser</argument>
            <argument name="failureProvider"
                      xsi:type="object">MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\Failure\CreateUserObserver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And then in the observer file, using a custom hidden input of the form, returned true.

```
<?php

namespace Iksula\EmployeeSignup\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;
use \MSP\ReCaptcha\Api\ValidateInterface;
use \MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\IsCheckRequiredInterface;
use \MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\FailureProviderInterface;
use \MSP\ReCaptcha\Model\Provider\ResponseProviderInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
class ReCaptchaObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        ResponseProviderInterface $responseProvider,
        ValidateInterface $validate,
        FailureProviderInterface $failureProvider,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress,
        IsCheckRequiredInterface $isCheckRequired,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->responseProvider = $responseProvider;
        $this->validate = $validate;
        $this->failureProvider = $failureProvider;
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        $this->isCheckRequired = $isCheckRequired;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $form_data = $this->_request->getParams();
        if (array_key_exists('custom_form_input_key', $form_data)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if ($this->isCheckRequired->execute()) {
                $reCaptchaResponse = $this->responseProvider->execute();
                $remoteIp = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    
                /** @var Action $controller */
                $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    
                if (!$this->validate->validate($reCaptchaResponse, $remoteIp)) {
                    $this->failureProvider->execute($controller ? $controller->getResponse() : null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```